# In following codeforce #158A Next Round problem how is lamda function working and also the logic in last line?

Tags: python-3.x

I was solving this problem on Codeforces: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/158/A .
I was just looking around other participants solution and came around this

```
i=lambda:map(int,input().split())
n,k=i()
l=list(i())
print(sum(v>=max(1,l[k-1])for v in l))
```

Please thoroughly  explain this code to me, as I am a beginner and self-taught. Thank You. This is my first question on stackoverflow so please  forgive any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lambda` statement creates an **anonymous function**. Writing `i = lambda: map(int,input().split())` is equivalent to writing:

```py
def i():
    map(int,input().split())
```

Note that what the user did is a bad practice: there is no point in creating an anonymous function, only to then give it a name (`i` in this case, which is, by the way, not a descriptive name and should be avoided as well). They're called "anonymous" for a reason.

So having a function object stored in `i`, it can then be called like any other function by writing `i()`.

The last line uses a **generator**. You can read up on them separately, as there are plenty of comprehensive guides to them and other Python features already.

In short, they are *similar* (but not the same as) a `for` loop run in-place: `x for x in range(5)` is a generator that contains numbers in the range 0 to 5 (excluded).

The user is iterating through the numbers in `l`, and for each of them they check whether it (`v`) is more or equal to whichever the highest number (`max()`) between 1 and `l[k-1]` is. This is a **boolean operation**: it will be either `True` or `False`.

In Python, `True` and `False` can also be used as numbers: `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so you can actually `sum()` them together: `sum()` takes all the elements of the generator and sums them together, so if the previous operation yielded all `False`, the total sum would be 0, if there were 3 elements for which the condition was `True` then the sum would be 3, etc.

Comment: Great explanation . Thanks a lot.